# Uninstall app then push out a log file to confirm in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and I've spent all day trying to get the answer but I keep hitting dead ends or not understanding some of the script mentioned.
So I have a script that I want to uninstall and application - that on its own does the job, however I need to output a log file if it has been found on the system, uninstalled.

Bear with me as it is very basic:
The uninstall part is

```
cd "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\app_2_remove"
.\Update.exe --uninstall
```

I have this to detect if the .exe exists

```
$FileName = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\app_2_remove\app_2_remove.exe"
```

But I'm not sure on the syntax for if it exists write to a log file at say c:\file.txt, if not then exit as succeded.

your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Read about the `Test-Path` command using the command `help Test-Path -Full`. `Test-Path` will tell you if the file does or does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This did the job

```
if (Test-Path -Path C:\Users\$($env:USERNAME)\AppData\Local\app_2_remove\app_2_remove.exe -PathType Leaf)
 {
cd "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\app_2_remove" .\Update.exe --uninstall
if (!(Test-Path -Path C:\file.txt -PathType Leaf))
{
New-Item -ItemType File -Path "C:\file.txt" -Force
 }
write-output "File was removed" |Out-File -FilePath C:\file.txt
}
```